# UE4 using a Function as parameter with it's own parameters, C++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am trying to set a timer, and use a function with in. I read the timer documentation and figured out how it works. You setting a timer with a timer_handler and a function to execute. Here's the problem. I can only give function without parameters.

```
GetWorldTimerManager().SetTimer(timer_handle1, this, &actor_class:Foo, 2.f, false, 1.f);
```

This "Foo" function can't take any arguments. But it should be. Basically, how can i translate it the form of it taking parameters?
I read about the Function Pointers and DELEGATE . Are these useful for this situation? If they are, is there any example or tutorial you can suggest?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For C++ I would say have a look at lambdas, maybe UE4 engine accepts them too or you can bind them to delegates. Otherwise I would say scan documentation/ue4 forum  for bind delegate with parameters and/or return value (disclaimer, I've not done any coding for UE4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the overload of `SetTimer` that [takes in a lambda](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/FTimerManager/SetTimer/4/). Then call your function with parameters inside the lambda.

```
GetWorld()->GetTimerManager().SetTimer(
                timer_handle1,
                [&]() { this->Foo(123); },
                2.f,
                false,
                1.f);
```